# compress html pages on Nginx with mod_strip

Tags: nginx, php, raid

I have installed Nginx 1.4.7 on my VPS and compiled mod_strip from this site https://github.com/evanmiller/mod_strip and tried to run it on my vhost block as it says in the manual like the code below: [Nginx HttpStrip Module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpStripModule)

```
 location / {
    strip on;
}
```

surprisingly, it doesn't work. my files are .php extension and thought it would work anyways!!

I checked whether the module was compiled correctly or not, and found out everything is just fine.

I ran the following to make sure about that:

```
$ sudo nginx -v
```

and yes it is there showing!!

any idea what went wrong in here??

**Update #1** this is my vhost block where strip command is:

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        access_log off;
        strip on;
}
```

Comment: Show full nginx config. I guess you should put this directive into location which handles your php files

Comment: ok, I will update my question with php handler.

Comment: Does your php script returns right `Content-Type` header?

Comment: when I test it using curl, I get this: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` that means it works, right?